# In Infopath how to exclude Saturdays and Sundays while calculating the Due Date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

In Infopath i have two datepicker, if i select any date from the first date picker, it has to add 15 days and should display in second datepicker excluding saturday and sundays.

I tried using today() and addDays() functions but not works.

If Any idea, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the something as given below but not sure though:(

http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/how-to-calculate-difference-between-dates-excluding-saturdays-and

I created two date pickers in SPD  named Issued and completed , and then i added a calculated column .. added the formula below to it , set the data type as text only and it worked ,

```
= ( [Completed] - [Issued] )
- ( ROUNDDOWN( ( [Completed] - [Issued] ) / 7 , 0 ) * 2 )
- ( IF( WEEKDAY( [Issued] ) = 7 , 1 , 0 ) )
- ( IF( WEEKDAY( [Completed] ) = 1 , 1 , 0 ) )
- 1
```

It calculated the weekdays only and excluded weekends

Thanks

Comment: Yes this work fine, If we change the data type from text to Date it shows irrelevant dates, Is there any possibility to get the correct calculated date.